# How to split remaining path from the last path of a url

Tags: java, android, split

I have a `fileUrl` given to me by my server `resources/upload/pdf/APPLE ははは.pdf`.

My problem is how to get `resources/upload/pdf/` since I can take the last path of the url which is `APPLE ははは.pdf` by using this code:

```
public static String getLastPathFromUrl(String url) {
    return url.replaceFirst(".*/([^/?]+).*", "$1");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
   File file=new File("resources/upload/pdf/APPLE ははは.pdf");
   System.out.println(file.getPath().replaceAll(file.getName(),""));
```

Out put:

```
   resources/upload/pdf/
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I do this without associating it yet with `File`. How do I split them apart if its data type is `String`?